# in vs over in present perfect tense

Tags: grammaticality

What's the difference between these two -

1. I've been to the dentist quite a few times over the past few days .
2. I've been to the dentist quite a few times in the past few days .

Answer (score 1):

*Over* has to be used with a specific *span of time.*

I've been to the dentist quite a few times *over the past few days.*
There were many battle casualties *over the centuries.*

*In* can be used my flexibly.

I've been to the dentist quite a few times *in my life.*
The eye has evolved quite a few times *in history.*

You cannot substitute over in these examples.

Wrong: I've been to the dentist quite a few times *over my life.*

Wrong: The eye has evolved quite a few times *over history.*

You'd have to substitute or add a span of time to use *over* in these examples.

Correct: I've been to the dentist quite a few times *over the decades of my life.*
Correct: The eye has evolved quite a few times *over the aeons of history.*

In your example, you can use either, but they expressing slightly different things.